# Generate XML Documentation for a Single File

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, xml-documentation

I want to configure my project to automatically generate an XML documentation file on every build but **only for one specific file**. How do I do this in Visual Studio 2013? I found an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x4sa0ak0(v=vs.100).aspx) describing how to enable XML documentation generation for a project but not for a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx). It is a free add-in for Visual Studio that automatically generates XML documentation comments.